# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen for external URL / Rails 6.11 / Ruby 3

Tags: ruby

This was working fine in Rails 6 but now upgrading Rails and Ruby to 6.11 and 3, it's triggering this "classic" error. Basically, to be short, for example this external URL direct to Firefox logo, using the Rails console:

```
require 'open-uri'
open("https://brandemia.org/sites/default/files/inline/images/firefox_logo.jpg")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from (irb):1:in `<main>'
        3: from (irb):2:in `rescue in <main>'
        2: from (irb):2:in `open'
        1: from (irb):2:in `initialize'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://brandemia.org/sites/default/files/inline/images/firefox_logo.jpg)
```

In the app same error. Before the Rails and Ruby upgrade (with Ruby 2.5.8 and Rails 6.0.3.1) this was working perfectly fine.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, @Dario. I dont quite understand your question (you do not really phrase one). Is your Rails executing `open("https....")` or is your rails app running at `brandemia.org....` and not **serving** the firefox_logo.jpg ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Before Ruby 3.0, `open-uri` used to overwrite `Kernel#open` with its own version which also supports reading from external URLs rather than simply opening local files or running commands.

Mixing those two use-cases was quite dangerous however and had the potential for serious vulnerabilities if the passed URL was not ensured to be safe everywhere (including third-party code using `Kernel#open`).

As such, this behavior to overwrite `Kernel#open` was deprecated in Ruby 2.7 and finally removed in Ruby 3.0. To open an external URL, you can use the following code instead:

```
URI.open("https://brandemia.org/sites/default/files/inline/images/firefox_logo.jpg")
```

Comment: Exactly. I solved it this afternoon and this was it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Excellent explanation! This solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great writeup - exactly the solution/explanation I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I am not exactly sure where the change comes from, but

```rb
require 'open-uri'

uri = 'https://brandemia.org/sites/default/files/inline/images/firefox_logo.jpg'
URI.open(uri) # ! instead of open without URI
```

should work.

**Update**
`open-uri` did declare `Kernel#open` until the 3.0 release. Apparently that was deprecated in 2.7. From now on, you need to call `URI.open` . See the commit here: https://github.com/ruby/open-uri/commit/53862fa35887a34a8060aebf2241874240c2986a .

Comment: Exactly. I solved it this afternoon and this was it. Thanks for the answer!